# Open Excel files in read-only mode if already open by another user in write mode

Tags: windows-server-2012, microsoft-excel

I've been all over Google for the past days and I simply can't find a solution to this that would work in this setup.

The setup: Windows Server 2012 R2 (RDS), Office 2016, file server is 2012R2.

The problem:

- User1 opens an Excel file either from the fileserver or from Microsoft SharePoint online in write mode.
- User2 opens the same Excel sheet - also in write mode and is not prompted that it is already being edited by another user.
- User1 saves changes and exits
- User2 saves changes and exits, hence changes by User1 is lost.

I have a vague memory that it was possible, centrally and NOT per sheet, to setup a notification that the sheet is already opened in write mode by another user. Any ideas on this?

Comment: This usually happens automatically. Typically, you don't need to do anything extra to get the "already opened by another user" message, if the workbook is on a network fileshare. Do you have this problem on both a network fileshare and SharePoint? Or just one or the other?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan, and I am aware that this is default behaviour, hence I'm confused as to why it doesn't behave this way any longer.
It is the same whether it's opened on sharepoint or network share/mapped drive.